# Height of Border according to size of text

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a metroapp using XAML and C#, and I'm using localization where text will be dynamic and differ from language to language. My code is structured as below - TextBlock inside Border.

```
<Border>
      <TextBlock Text="Foo">
      </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

So is there any way to change the height and width of the Border or TextBlock according to the size of the text?

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do did this: (tested it quickly, should work)

```
                    <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue" Background="SlateBlue" Width="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=ActualHeight}">
                         <TextBlock FontSize="45" Name="tb" Text="12345" Foreground="AliceBlue"/>
                    </Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` property of the `FrameworkElement` class from which the `TextBlock` class is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it inside `StackPanel` should work.